# Как отобразить сообщение для первой новой записи?

Tags: javascript, angular

У меня имеется условие если появляется новая запись то должно отобразиться сообщение. И у меня возникает проблема в счетчике. Когда происходит добавление новой первой записи счетчик на данном этапе равен еще 0 и из-за этого сообщение не отображается.

Если установить условие:

```
if (this.counter >= 0) {}
```

То при каждой перезагрузке страницы будет всплывать мое сообщение.

Как это можно исправить?

**ts:**

```
counter = 0;
load() {
  this.ngUnsubscribe = timer(0, 1000).pipe(
    switchMap(() => this._orders.getAllOrders()),
    filter(data => data.length !== (this.orders || []).length)
  ).subscribe(orders => {
    this.orders = orders;
    if (this.counter > 0) {
    this._toast.warning('Новое.', 'Внимание!', {
        closeButton: true,
        disableTimeOut: true
      });
    }
    this.counter++;
  }, error => {
    this._toast.error(error.error.message);
  })
}
```

Comment: Если что после перезагрузки была информация то используйте Cookie или Local Storage

Answer (score 0):

Можете сохранить состояние одним из способов [Cookie SessionStorage LocalStorage](https://medium.com/fafnur/%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-web-storage-%D0%B2-angular-9-12525450a02b)

и при следующей загрузке посмотреть имеется ли запись в хранилище, если имеется то взять значение если нет то показать ваше сообщение.

> Веб хранилища в браузерах реализованы в виде LocalStorage и Session
> Storage. Также для обмена данными между Сервером и браузером
> используются куки, которые представляют собой ключ значение.
> Управление куками можно тоже в какой-то мере назвать хранилищем, но
> очень абстрактно.